# SQL to select max record that is not in the future

Tags: mysql

My table structure looks like this

**tblclients**

```
clientid
clientname
```

**tblfacilities**

```
facilityid
facilityname
```

**tblclientfacilities**

```
clientid
facilityid
moveindate
```

I allow my users to enter a future date as a move in date, what I want to do is select the current facility that my client resides in. I've tried

```
SELECT 
 clientid,
 facilityid,
 moveindate

FROM 
 tblclientfacilities
WHERE 
 MAX(tblclientfacilities.moveindate) <= now()
GROUP BY
  tblclientfacilities.clientid
```

Obviously that's not working. Could someone get me on the right track here? Thanks!

Comment: does `tblclientfacilities` have a primary key?

Comment: Primary key is all three fields.

Comment: Clientid, facilityid then moveindate

Comment: hit enter too soon :/

Comment: OK, then my point about creating the index is valid. If you made it `clientId, moveInDate, facilityId`, you would not need the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  clientId,
        (
        SELECT  facilityId
        FROM    tblclientfacilities cf
        WHERE   cf.clientId = c.clientId
                AND cf.moveDate <= NOW()
        ORDER BY
                cf.clientId DESC, moveDate DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) AS currentFacility
FROM    tblclients c
```

Create a unique index on `tblclientfacilities (clientId, moveDate, facilityId)` for this to work fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HAVING` for aggregate functions.

```
HAVING MAX(tblclientfacilities.moveindate) <= now()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `group by` clause consider using the `having` clause if you want to filter on the aggregated results

```
SELECT 
 clientid,
 moveindate,
 facilityid
FROM 
 tblclientfacilities
GROUP BY
  tblclientfacilities.clientid
HAVING MAX(tblclientfacilities.moveindate) <= now()
```

Doc: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: `2, 5, 2013-04-01 |
2, 6, 2013-04-03 | 
2, 11, 2013-04-02` When I have this data in my table I'm always returning `2, 5, 2013-04-01` Why would this be?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the usage of `where` with the usage of `having`.

A quick reference:

```
SELECT # Desired columns and expressions
FROM # Source tables, and possible joins
WHERE # Filter conditions on the raw data
GROUP BY # Fields you want your data to be grouped-by
HAVING # Filter conditions on the grouped data
```

Answer (score 0):

Join your client/facility/date records against the records of each client's most recent move-in:

```
    SELECT tcf.*
      FROM tblclientfacilities tcf
INNER JOIN (  SELECT clientid, MAX(moveindate) AS moveindate
                FROM tblclientfacilities
               WHERE moveindate < CURRENT_DATE
            GROUP BY 1, 2) most_recent_moveins
        ON tcf.clientid = most_recent_moveins.clientid
           AND
           tcf.moveindate = most_recent_moveins.moveindate)
```